# Losing mounted shared drive on Pi reboot

Tags: networking, debian, mount

I am able to successfully mount a drive with

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/share /mnt/destination -o username=user,password=pass,domain=dom
```

and navigate to the share with

```
cd mnt/destination
```

However, once the Pi is rebooted I lose my mount. Any ideas as to why that is happening?

Comment: What OS are you using? Add it into fstab to mount on boot.

Comment: *"...why that is happening?"* -> Because you rebooted ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line to /etc/fstab.  Linux uses this file to see what drives to mount when it boots.  Try adding something like this at the end of /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.2/share  /mnt/destination  cifs  _netdev,username=user,password=pass  0   0
```

I don't think you need to specify a domain.